# Flurry Analaytics fails to show events on click

Tags: ios, swift, flurry-analytics

I know that there is a delay in Flurry reporting, however, flurry fails to show some events (ie, didselectrowatindexpath)
Any idea? I did about the code, I register with my ID

```
        Flurry.setCrashReportingEnabled(true)
        Flurry.startSession(@"SESSION_START")
        Flurry.logEvent("session_Name", withParameters: nil)
        Flurry.setBackgroundSessionEnabled(false)
        Flurry.setDebugLogEnabled(true)
        Flurry.setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled(true)
        Flurry.setSessionReportsOnPauseEnabled(true)
        Flurry.setEventLoggingEnabled(true)
```

**Logs from Flurry Analytics :**
08/02/16 11:51:28 IST  1.1 (iPhone)  Apple iPod Touch 6G

```
1) getFeedsSuccess
2) reloadNavBar
3) updateLogoImage
4) getLoadUpdatedDataInAdvance
5) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView
6) numberOfItemsInSection
7) sizeForItemAtIndexPath
8) cellForItemAtIndexPath
```

Note: Fails to show didselectrowatindexpath . Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Note : I solved the issue .Please try this   Flurry.setShouldGroupAccessibilityChildren(true)

Answer (score 0):

Flurry by default sends `FlurryLogLevelCriticalOnly`

> //Default, outputs only critical log events`

Try to declare log level,

```
Flurry.setLogLevel(FlurryLogLevelAll)
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks iSashok.But still it fails to show didselectedrowatindexpath